# Hibernate, Spring Data, insert id of table parent on table child

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying insert the id of Person in child table 'Contact'. But the Hibernate stores the value null at fk column.

I perform the mapping of a DTO to the entity, where it already brings the person's data and contact. In the end I have to save the person entity.

There is a table inheritance!

Parent table:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "CHAR(2)", length = 2)
public abstract class Person implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person")
    @Cascade(value={org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private @Getter @Setter Set<Contact> contacts;

}
```

Table Company extends of Person:

```
@Entity
@Table
@DiscriminatorValue(value="PJ")
public class Company extends Person implements Serializable {

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private @Getter @Setter LocalDate constitutionDate;

}
```

And where is the problem!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Contact implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private @Getter Integer id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(16)", length = 16, nullable = false)
    private @Getter @Setter String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false,targetEntity=Person.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id")
    private @Getter @Setter Person person;

    public Contact() {}

    public Contact(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the best strategy?

Excuse me for my poor English!

Answer (score 2):

Can't find nothing obvious that's wrong but let me try some things:

1. Your cascade annotation on Person class doesn't need the specific Hibernate enumeration You can use like :

---

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "cliente")
```

2. In your ManyToOne annotation on Contact class please try to add:

---

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
```

BTW, an inheritance relationship between Person and Company doesn't seem logic to me, but that has nothing to do with your stated problem for sure.

Comment: Apenas coloquei o resumo aqui rsrs. I'll try it here!